# How to sync contacts from my android Phone Contact to my android application like Whatsapp n Skype

Tags: android, ios

I am making an android application similar to whatsapp what i want to know is how to synchronize android contacts with my application so that the numbers which are registered with my application and are also in my android contacts got a symbol. For example in your contact list you see a skype icon or whatsapp icon with those contacts who are registered with skype or whatsapp.
Also want to display that contacts in contacts of my application.
Anyone can guide me what to do.
Thanks! in advance....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class ContactActivity extends Activity {

Cursor cursor;
ArrayList<String> NameList=new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listveiew_lv);

//  NameList=new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,NameList);
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);   
        int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

        String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
        String phone = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);    
        NameList.add(phone);

        System.out.println("Name is :"+name +" number is : "+phone);
        System.out.println("Name is :"+name +" number is : "+phone);
        System.out.println("Name is :"+name +" number is : "+phone);



    }

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), NameList.get(arg2), 1).show();
        }
    });
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    super.startActivityForResult(i, 1001);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1001:

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Cursor s = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);

            if (s.moveToFirst()) {
                String phoneNum = s.getString(s.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), phoneNum, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        break;

    }

}
```

}